# Admin panel url redirect to live site where frontend url works correctly in development site

Tags: magento-1.8, redirect, development, admin-panel

There is an issue i have been trying to solve for the past 2 days.

I created devlopment site for a live site.

Frontend url of the development site works properly.

Whereas the backend(Admin Panel) redirects to the live site.

I tried out the following

1) Cleared **Cache and session**

2) Check the **web/unsecure/base_url** and **web/secure/base_url** . Both have been assigned with the development site url

3)Also I have **checked the .htaccess**. There is no redirection mentioned.

Somebody help me.

Answer (score 1):

Redirects might be cached by the browser.. try to use another one

> Check the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url

Check this setting storewide.

Answer (score 0):

You should check weather admin/url/custom and admin/url/use_custom_path are not set to your live domain.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem for no special reason. I moved with my notebook to another location and possibly due to another ip address the admin panel started to redirect me to frontend if i managed to click on any link on the dashboard. 
Using another browser i logged into admin and in
Configuration->General->Web->Session Validation Settings
I set everything to NO:

Validate REMOTE_ADDR -> No

Validate HTTP_VIA -> No

Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR -> No

Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT -> No

Use SID on Frontend -> No

Not sure what other surprises will happen due to such settings but the annoying redirecting stopped